# estimating mu and sigma of lognormal distribution from 1st k order statistics samples

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution, order-statistics

How can I estimate mu and sigma of lognormal distribution from 1st k order statistics samples? I am not a pro in statistics but I have to get it done. Would greatly appreciate your helps.

Comment: By exponentiating, you can transform this to a problem of estimating a Normal from its first k order statistics. How big is k relative to the sample size?